# How to display values of d3 animated sparkline graph into tooltip?

Tags: d3.js

I want to display value of array into tool tip when mouse over on sparkline. I have adapted code from  http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/1148374

I added following code to display array value into tool tip when mouse over on sparkline, but its showing only first index value.

```
var tooltip = d3.select(id)
    .append("div")
    .attr("id","toolTip"+toolTipId)
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("background", "#6a7883")
    .style("color", "white")
    .style("height", "20px")
    .style("width", toolTipWidth)
    .style("text-align", "center")
    .style("font-size", "11px")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
    d3.select(id+" svg path")
    .data(arr)      
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i){tooltip.text(msgToolTipPrefix+" "+arr[i]+""+msgToolTipPostfix); return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
    .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

Comment: Remove the `return` on both your `mousemove` and `mouseout` function.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo Furtado. I'm removing first index value and pushing into last index and shifting a array. I removed return on both mousemove and mouseout. But here I values always zero. So, its still showing first index value on mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular example the line is represented by the only one SVG path (DOM element). D3 binds data to DOM elements, and not to the path segments. That is why you always see the same data.

You can split line into separate hoverable segments (like in [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1117287)). In result you will have an array of SVG paths, with mouse events bound. You can use your tooltip code with minor tweaks there:

```js
path
   .on("mouseover", function(d) { tooltip.text("Hello "+d[0][1]+ "."); return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
   .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
   .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

Please note that you may want to interpolate the Y data according to mouse event, as far as I know, D3 will not do that automatically (and I do not know how to do that when something like 'spline' interpolation is used to render the line).